# Get html element one after the other with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My [div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS762.png) `#chat` receive some text and some select element.

I would like to get the text (in my case: 'hello how are you today') with the help of JQuery.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
$('#chat').each(function(index){
      if(this == 'select'){
          var test=$('option:selected');
          MyTable.push(test.text+" ");
      }
      else{
          MyTable.push(this+" ");
      }
    });
```

Comment: To be able to help you, we need all the required code. And in this case, that includes your HTML. You also might also want to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: **Edit** Nevermind, there are too many flaws hear to cover in chat.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div>
 <p id="text">hello how</p>
  //dropdown 1
  //drop down 2
  //dropdown 3
</div>
```

for each element use

var value =  $("#yourDropDownId").text();

to get the text or use

var value = $("#yourDropDownId").val();

to get the value

then just push  mytable.push(value)